# Setting environment variables in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, prolog, environment-variables

I am trying to set my environment variable in windows 7 so that I can call prolog from the command line. I went into the environment variables under system settings, and edited it so that it looks like this.

```
C:\Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++;C:\Program Files\pl\bin\prolog;
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong here, as I keep getting the message

```
prolog is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Both Python and Notepad++ work just fine the way I have them, and I have double checked to make sure my path name is correct. I DID change the name of the prolog executable from swipl-win to prolog, but that shouldn't make a difference, as I did this with python as well (python changed to python27). Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Answer (score 4):

Is `prolog` (the executable) inside a folder also called "prolog"? If it's inside "bin", your path should be:

```
C:\Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++;C:\Program Files\pl\bin;
```

(that's probably the case, since in my system - I have Swi-Prolog in Windows XP - there is a folder called "bin", no subfolders, with the executable `plwin.exe` inside it)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SWI-Prolog  then add below path in your PATH environment variable:

For 64 bit system/installation:
C:\Program Files\swipl\bin

For 32 bit system/installation:
C:\Program Files (x86)\swipl\bin

Answer (score 0):

is the path correct? Your notepad++ runs from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\'...
your prolog runs from '\Program Files\'....

Comment: Probably prolog is a 64bit program and notepad++ a 32bit one, right?