# image::magick not installing with cpan in perl v5.14.2 from dwimperl

Tags: image-processing, installation, cpan

I am attempting to rebuild my development/test environment on a new laptop running windows7 32 bit. imageMagick is one of the modules I had installed in an (ancient) version on my old laptop. I have downloaded and installed perl from dwimperl, which is v5.14.2 and had a couple modules install, and several did not.

- cpanm Image::Magick - failed
- cpanm DB_File - failed
- cpanm Time::HiRes - failed

I searched around and found a discussion on magick failing to install on v5.12, but couldn't tell if that was supposed to have been fixed, or if I need to attempt to recreate the fix discussed for 5.12

should I try installing perl from Strawberry? looks like it is a little newer v5.18 ?
is there something I can tweak and re-run cpan installs?

I installed the binaries from imagemagick, from [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) first, then cpan again, and cpan still fails....

This is the top part of the build log down to where it really goes south and starts kicking out errors:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.6941 on perl 5.014002 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
Work directory is C:\Users\dtbaker/.cpanm/work/1377281741.8420
You have make C:\Dwimperl\c\bin\dmake.exe
You have LWP 6.03
Falling back to Archive::Tar 1.80
Searching Image::Magick on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Image::Magick
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/J/JC/JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.86.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking PerlMagick-6.86.tar.gz
Entering PerlMagick-6.86
META.yml/json not found. Creating skelton for it.
Configuring PerlMagick-6.86
Running Makefile.PL
################################### WARNING! ###################################
# It seems that you are trying to install Perl::Magick on a MS Windows box with
# perl + gcc compiler (e.g. strawberry perl), however we cannot find ImageMagick
# binaries installed on your system.
#
# Please check the following prerequisites:
#
# 1) You need to have installed ImageMagick Windows binaries from
#    http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows
#
# 2) We only support dynamic (DLL) ImageMagick binaries
#    note: it is not possible to mix 32/64-bit binaries of perl and ImageMagick
#
# 3) During installation select that you want to install ImageMagick's
#    development files (libraries+headers)
#
# 4) You also need to have ImageMagick's directory in your PATH
#    note: we are checking the presence of convert.exe and/or identify.exe tools
#
# 5) You might need Visual C++ Redistributable Package installed on your system
#    see instructions on ImageMagick's Binary Release webpage
#
# We are gonna continue, but chances for successful build are very low!
################################################################################
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lMagickCore-6.Q16
Writing Makefile for Image::Magick
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.62)
Building and testing Image-Magick-6.86
cp Magick.pm blib\lib\Image\Magick.pm
AutoSplitting blib\lib\Image\Magick.pm (blib\lib\auto\Image\Magick)
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe C:\Dwimperl\perl\lib\ExtUtils\xsubpp  -typemap C:\Dwimperl\perl\lib\ExtUtils\typemap -typemap typemap  Magick.xs > Magick.xsc && C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e mv -- Magick.xsc Magick.c
gcc -c      -s -O2 -DWIN32  -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2    -DVERSION=\"6.86\"    -DXS_VERSION=\"6.86\"  "-IC:\Dwimperl\perl\lib\CORE"  -D_LARGE_FILES=1 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H Magick.c
Magick.xs:60:31: error: magick/MagickCore.h: No such file or directory
Magick.xs:167: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'MagickRealType'
Magick.xs:188: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'ImageInfo'
Magick.xs:210: error: 'MagickNoiseOptions' undeclared here (not in a function)
```

Comment: Why did the install fail, do you have more information than just the "failed" messages you've listed?

Comment: here is the build log from cpanm:

Comment: I can't paste in the build log, its too long... the first error it gives is.... Unpacking PerlMagick-6.86.tar.gz
Entering PerlMagick-6.86
META.yml/json not found. Creating skelton for it.
Configuring PerlMagick-6.86
Running Makefile.PL
################################### WARNING! ###################################
# It seems that you are trying to install Perl::Magick on a MS Windows box with
# perl + gcc compiler (e.g. strawberry perl), however we cannot find ImageMagick
# binaries installed on your system........ which is weird since I did install the binaries directly.

Comment: Edit your question and add the information there. Please don't put it in the comments.

Comment: ok, I will try to paste in the top of the log....

Answer (score 0):

> however we cannot find ImageMagick binaries installed on your system.

Is ImageMagick is in your path, as recommanded in the 4) point? Open `cmd.exe` and type `convert -v` or `convert.exe -v`. If you don't see informations about Image Magick (Windows have a built-in `convert` command), it is very likely [you have to add it to your path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552973/setting-environment-variables-in-windows-7).

You also have to check points 1), 3), and 5). After that try again to run installation process through `cpanm`.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to install for Citrus Perl, I discovered on debugging through the Perl part of the install that the mingw64 install had not included 'pexports.exe'. Downloading that from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Extension/pexports/
and placing it in the mingw64 directory was necessary to solve the problem of a long list of library export symbols not found.
Prior to that I had also set the environment variables CPATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH, and CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH to point to the "include" directory of the ImageMagick install include directory in C:\Program Files (x86).  (When you install ImageMagick you should check the box to install also for Strawberry Perl.)